# Azure spatial anchor create watcher results in assertion error

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-spatial-anchors

I want to use azure spatial anchors to locate anchors from the cloud in my iOS app

I followed the docs and the sample project to setup the config and functions but when it comes to running I get a crash

```
let criteria = ASAAnchorLocateCriteria()
criteria?.identifiers = anchorIds
cloudSession.createWatcher(criteria)
```

results in

`Assertion failed: (([NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [props objectForKey: key]].length < 125)), function LogTelemetryEvent, file /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/SpatialServices/Core/Telemetry/src/ios/Telemetry.mm, line 436.`

Comment: Can you link the doc you are following? In this code you are sharing are you getting the criteria variable set as nil?

Comment: @AlbertoVega-MSFT I am following the official docs from Microsoft - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/how-tos/create-locate-anchors-swift

The criteria is not nil ....

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the spatial key